# Automatizar reinicialización de secuencia en PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Necesito hacer que una secuencia de posgresql se reinicialize a 0 cada cierto tiempo.

Para reinicializar la secuencia lo hago a través de:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE serial RESTART WITH 0;
```

Eso lo hago manualmente, necesito que por ejemplo cada 3 meses se reinicie a 0, pero automáticamente sin intervención de alguna persona.

**¿Podría usar algún trigger o función de PostgreSQL, cómo se haría?**

o **¿Debería usar algo como crontab en linux?**

Answer (score 2):

Las tareas programadas no son parte de la funcionalidad de PostgreSQL, para esto es necesario usar una aplicacion externa.

El pgAdmin tienen una herramienta extra que puede ayudar en esto, se llama [pgAgent](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgagent.php) y es un agente que permite realizar ese tipo de tareas...

Pero mi recomendación es usar crontab en linux o el programador de tareas en windows, en mi experiencia son más confiables, pero tienen la desventaja de que hay que administrarlas por fuera de PostgreSQL.